# $scope.$apply() not working after state navigation

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, cordova

I'm using cordova plugin to open an external url and download pdf, this will assign an object in code and this is shown in ui as an icon for file.

This is working fine in regular flow. if i go to next state (using $state.go) and come back to previous screen and try to do the same (downloading pdf file), the UI is not getting updated but the object is assigned.

I've used the $scope.$apply(); for updating the DOM. But not working

Divided the function to implement using promises. but not working

```
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(destDir, function (drootDir) {
              console.log('Access to the dest directory granted succesfully');
              drootDir.getDirectory(destFolder, {
                create: true
              }, function (ddir) {
                file.moveTo(ddir, destFileName, function () {
                  $scope.mainobject.pdfFile = {
                    'rootPath': destDir,
                    'folderPath': destFolder,
                    'fileName': destFileName
                  };
                  $scope.$apply();
                });
              });
            });
```

Comment: If the object being assigned is making the icon appear, then try to run `$scope.$apply()` again as soon as the controller is loaded. If you get a digest error, try putting that in a `setTimeout()`.

Comment: I tried your solutions already. but it did not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try updating the angular element by using `$timeout` function. 
Include assigning the object inside the `$timeout` function.